# Understanding the use of Capstan Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I'm currently working on the analysis of a current capstan, I want to analyze this system using the capstan equation. [image: Image of a theoretical approach on a capstan]

The current capstan I'm working on has been built on the following parameters

Approximate weight 7,000 lbs

Motor: 40/20HP, 460 V / 3PH / 60 Hz

Capstan Barrel Size: theta 24"

Running pull: approx 40,000lbs , at 15 ft/min and 30ft/min

Capstan bollard load: 100,000 lbs at centerline barrel

The rope is angled 5 degrees away from the pull line allowing the line to walk up the side of the capstan and push the previous wraps to the side.

Given the information on the analysis of the capstan such as radius, pulling load, and pulling speed, can I adequately showcase this relationship using the Capstan Equation?

Comment: Why do you call it a “current” capstan?

Comment: It's been having gearing issues so I doubt it stays in function much longer